# Upload images/video to google cloud storage using Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I have read the question from [Sending images to google cloud storage using google app engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9237747/sending-images-to-google-cloud-storage-using-google-app-engine).

However, the codes in the answer that the file will upload to Blobstore first, so the file can not be exceeded 32MB.

How can I upload the large file to Google Cloud Storage directly?

I have checked the official document [Upload Objects](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/how-tos/upload), but I still don't know how to write a form to post a large file.

Comment: there is no 32mb filesize limit on the blobstore. it is a limit on how many mb you can read in one api call. `the maximum size of Blobstore data that can be READ by the application with one API call is 32 megabytes.`

Comment: @aschmid00: Thanks for your comment. However,  I still don't know how to upload file to Blobstore without calling API...

Comment: its not the api call to upload it that limits you but the api call to read the blob. you should read the docs first https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/overview#Uploading_a_Blob you need to generate the upload url when the form is rendered or get it with an ajax call on a later moment

Comment: @aschmid00: Thanks for your fast reply. I do read the docs you mention, and have used in my web site. But I still want to know how to use a form to upload a large file to Cloud Storage directly  and read it later.

Comment: this should help you out https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlestorage/overview

Comment: @aschmid00: I have read that. Writing a txt file to Cloud Storage is no problem, but I know nothing about how to upload a image or large file to Cloud Storage directly...

Comment: @Jerry, unfortunately nobody can help you (and me as well). Nobody post a sample working code. I did it with Java just attaching pieces of code together, taken from different websites, but i have a problem with file larger than 32Mb even if they tell that Google Cloud Storage has "no limits".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

easy since 1.7.0

```
upload_url = blobstore.create_upload_url('/upload_handler', gs_bucket_name='my_bucket')
```

Will upload straight to Google Storage and return you blob keys that point to the uploads in Cloud Storage.

Comment: wow, it works! Thank you!  Is it possible to use the upload_filename to setup the filename in bucket?

Comment: not currently - we use a "random" filename so we have the same semantic as uploads to blobstore, where you can upload the same file time after time and get a new blob generated.

Comment: @StuartLangley and how to retrieve this filename? Using get_uploads() in BlobstoreUploadHandler just returns a weird key.

Comment: This issue looks like it was fixed as of Mar 11, 2013 https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/wiki/SdkForJavaReleaseNotes

Answer (score 2):

upload_url = blobstore.create_upload_url('/upload', gs_bucket_name='mybucketname')

does get the upload with the blob key to the cloud storage but it still puts the uploaded file in the blobstore as well.

Comment: I am using GAE1.7.3 and it is still uploading it to the blobstore as well on the GCS.

Comment: i confirm that it is still uploading to both blobstore and GCS.