# Direct upload to local Google Cloud Storage

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

Per the answer here: [Upload images/video to google cloud storage using Google App Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11364878/upload-images-video-to-google-cloud-storage-using-google-app-engine)

I'm calling:

```
upload_url = blobstore.create_upload_url(url, gs_bucket_name='my_bucket')
```

However, I'm still seeing the file being uploaded to the blobstore and not cloud storage.

This is on a local dev server and I'm verifying by checking the datastore kinds `BlobInfo` and `GsFileInfo`. When I use the Cloud Storage API directly to create and write to a file then I get a `GsFileInfo`, but when I try to upload directly to local Cloud Storage in the manner above then I get a new `BlobInfo` entity.

Any suggestions?

Also, is there another way to view the contents of local Cloud Storage? Any way to configure `gsutil` against local?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On the development server, cloud storage is simulated, and all blobs are uploaded to the blobstore.

Comment: That's what I was thinking. Thanks for confirming!

Comment: So, in local development the Cloud Storage not "store" files we put there? (maybe in tmp or somewhere else)?

Comment: it stores them locally - not in the real cloud storage service.

Comment: Thank you Stuart! But I'm using get_serving_url (with gs_create_key) in local dev server and I get an url that could not be opened. Should it work in local dev server? (http://localhost:8080/_ah/img/encoded_gs_file:L2dzL215cGlsZW9mL2F2YXRhcnMvYWhCa1pYWi1iWGx3YVd4bGIyWXRaR1YyY2hFTEVnUlZjMlZ5R0lDQWdJQ0FnSUFLREE=)

Comment: Sorry, I'm getting OError: decoder jpeg not available, probably some problem with my PIL installation, I'll check it