# Upload to Google Cloud Storage

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, google-api-python-client

I'm trying to upload to cloud storage from my app engine app but it keeps uploading the name of the file instead of its contents.

The html is pretty simple:

```html
<form id="uploadbanner" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/upload">
    <input id="fileupload" name="myfile" type="file" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" id="submit" />
</form>
```

The python element goes like this:

```python
class Uploader(webapp2.RequestHandler):
def get(self):
    objectname = '%s'%str(uuid.uuid4())
    objectpath = '/gs/bucketname/%s' %objectname
    upload = self.request.get('myfile')
    writable = files.gs.create(filename=objectpath, mime_type='application/octet-stream', acl='public-read')
    with files.open(writable, 'a') as f:
        f.write(upload)
    files.finalize(writable)
    self.response.write('done')
```

I know `f.write(upload)` is definitely wrong but I have no idea what i'm supposed to replace it with

Answer (score 2):

You should probably let the browser upload directly to GCS, and only get your handler called afterwards.

To get a short overview of how this can be done, look at this post: [Upload images/video to google cloud storage using Google App Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11364878/upload-images-video-to-google-cloud-storage-using-google-app-engine)

Even if the blobstore API seems to be called in this example, the files are uploaded to Cloud Storage.

Answer (score 2):

It needs to be POST not GET, so add `method="POST"` to the form and make the python function post instead of get too, that sorted it out for me.