# Upload ndarray(image in OpenCV) on to google cloud storage as a .jpg or .png

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, opencv3.0

I have a similar issues like [How to upload a bytes image on Google Cloud Storage from a Python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46078088/how-to-upload-a-bytes-image-on-google-cloud-storage-from-a-python-script/47140336#comment86305324_47140336).

I tried this

```
from google.cloud import storage
import cv2
from tempfile import TemporaryFile
import google.auth
credentials, project = google.auth.default()
client = storage.Client()
# https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser/[bucket-id]/
bucket = client.get_bucket('document')
# Then do other things...
image=cv2.imread('/Users/santhoshdc/Documents/Realtest/15.jpg')
with TemporaryFile() as gcs_image:
    image.tofile(gcs_image)
    blob = bucket.get_blob(gcs_image)
    print(blob.download_as_string())
    blob.upload_from_string('New contents!')
    blob2 = bucket.blob('document/operations/15.png')

    blob2.upload_from_filename(filename='gcs_image')
```

This is the error that's posing up

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/Users/santhoshdc/Documents/ImageShapeSize/imageGcloudStorageUpload.py",
> line 13, in <module>
>     blob = bucket.get_blob(gcs_image)   File "/Users/santhoshdc/.virtualenvs/test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/cloud/storage/bucket.py",
> line 388, in get_blob
>     **kwargs)   File "/Users/santhoshdc/.virtualenvs/test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/cloud/storage/blob.py",
> line 151, in __init__
>     name = _bytes_to_unicode(name)   File "/Users/santhoshdc/.virtualenvs/test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/cloud/_helpers.py",
> line 377, in _bytes_to_unicode
>     raise ValueError('%r could not be converted to unicode' % (value,)) ValueError: <_io.BufferedRandom name=7> could not be
> converted to unicode
```

Can anyone guide me what's going wrong or what I'm doing incorrectly?

Comment: @A.Queue Please look into this

Answer (score 6):

As suggested by @A.Queue [in](https://pastebin.com/Jr6k3SW2)(gets deleted after 29 days)

```
from google.cloud import storage
import cv2
from tempfile import TemporaryFile

client = storage.Client()

bucket = client.get_bucket('test-bucket')
image=cv2.imread('example.jpg')
with TemporaryFile() as gcs_image:
    image.tofile(gcs_image)
    gcs_image.seek(0)
    blob = bucket.blob('example.jpg')
    blob.upload_from_file(gcs_image)
```

The file got uploaded,but uploading a `numpy ndarray` doesn't get saved as an image file on the `google-cloud-storage`

PS:

`numpy array` has to be convert into any image format before saving.

This is fairly simple, use the `tempfile` created to store the image, here's the code.

```
with NamedTemporaryFile() as temp:

    #Extract name to the temp file
    iName = "".join([str(temp.name),".jpg"])

    #Save image to temp file
    cv2.imwrite(iName,duplicate_image)

    #Storing the image temp file inside the bucket
    blob = bucket.blob('ImageTest/Example1.jpg')
    blob.upload_from_filename(iName,content_type='image/jpeg')

    #Get the public_url of the saved image 
    url = blob.public_url
```

Comment: was the issue solved in the end? I am asking because in the other question you have wrote that it was a issue with the path, but here you say it is unreadable.

Comment: @A.Queue Yes the issue was solved. `numpy array` direct upload will not be stored in image format hence unreadable. I have updated the code for `numpy array` first converted and stored in `tempfile` then uploaded

Comment: but you need to delete the file after you uplaoded. Otherwise the disk can be overfilled

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `blob = bucket.get_blob(gcs_image)` which makes no sense.  `get_blob()` is supposed to get a string argument, namely the name of the blob you want to get.  A *name*.  But you pass a file object.

I propose this code:

```
with TemporaryFile() as gcs_image:
    image.tofile(gcs_image)
    gcs_image.seek(0)
    blob = bucket.blob('documentation-screenshots/operations/15.png')
    blob.upload_from_file(gcs_image)
```

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/santhoshdc/Documents/ImageShapeSize/imageGcloudStorageUpload.py", line 34, in <module>
    blob2.upload_from_filename(filename='gcs_image')
  File "/Users/santhoshdc/.virtualenvs/test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/cloud/storage/blob.py", line 1021, in upload_from_filename
    with open(filename, 'rb') as file_obj:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'gcs_image'`.  This is the error I'm getting on removing those three lines

Comment: Urgs.  `filename='gcs_image'` makes no sense.  I'll add code I think might work to my answer.  Hang on.

Comment: @PrashantPanwar I added example code which should do the trick.

Comment: The program seems to work fine no errors, but there isn't any file being uploaded into the bucket. Trying to upload an image through `gsutil` in the terminal seems to upload the image. Have no idea where it is going wrong?

Comment: Maybe you need to `close()` the blob?  I didn't look that up.

Comment: Getting  AttributeError: ‘Blob’ object has no attribute ‘close’.

Comment: Maybe slashes are not allowed in the blob names?  As I said, I'm not familiar with the Google Cloud Services.

Comment: Scanning through https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/storage/blobs.html I found examples which inspired this: `from google.cloud.storage import Blob` — `blob = Blob('15.png', bucket)` — `blob.upload_from_file(gcs_image)`.  Could you test this?

Comment: Tried with [this code](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects#storage-upload-object-python) as well but still same issue. Getting confused here

Comment: Try running this code https://pastebin.com/Jr6k3SW2. It's mostly the same but without `google.auth` which is unnecessary here as google.cloud is handling everything in the background. It will be a good point of reference as I have  tried it and it works.

Comment: Where are you executing the script? Have you set all the necessary environment variables and checked that the bucket exists? I know this questions are to obvious but it never hurts to check.

Comment: I'm explaining my work in another post. You might get a clear picture there. @A.Queue

Comment: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49671827/upload-an-image-from-cloud-function-python-to-google-cloud-storage) @A.Queue

Comment: [pastebin.com/Jr6k3SW2](https://pastebin.com/Jr6k3SW2) Worked as expected Thank You @A.Queue but please check the above link.

Comment: Tried to upload a PIL `JpegImageFile`. I am getting `AttributeError: 'JpegImageFile' object has no attribute 'read'` @A.Queue

Comment: @A.Queue Could you please look into the link [here](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/3079#event-1560370122)

Comment: [`.tofile`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tofile.html) in  `image.tofile(gcs_image)` is saving an ndarray into your blob. So `blob2 = bucket.blob('document/operations/15.png')` isn't really a png file. If you want to write it as an image instead of ndarray maybe you can use  [`imwrite`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgcodecs/doc/reading_and_writing_images.html?highlight=imread#imwrite).