# No Error: Not able to see the uploaded file on the google cloud storage

Tags: python, opencv, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

Have a python code running on cloud function using [cloud function python](https://github.com/MartinSahlen/cloud-functions-python).

I'm processing an image on cloud. Now I want to save that image on `google-cloud-storage`

```
from google.cloud import storage
import cv2
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile
import os

client = storage.Client()

bucket = client.get_bucket('document')

image = cv2.imread('15.png')

with NamedTemporaryFile() as temp:
    print(type(temp.name)," ",temp.name)
    iName = "".join([str(temp.name),".jpg"])
    print(iName)
    cv2.imwrite(iName,image)
    print(os.path.exists(str(iName)))
    blob = bucket.blob('document/Test15.jpg')
    blob.upload_from_filename(iName)
```

My output

> < class 'str' >
>
> /var/folders/5j/bqk11bqj4r55f8975mn__72m0000gq/T/tmplcgzaucx
>
> /var/folders/5j/bqk11bqj4r55f8975mn__72m0000gq/T/tmplcgzaucx.jpg
>
> True

Don't know what's going wrong

can anyone suggest a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Silly mistake, turns out

`blob = bucket.blob('document/Test15.jpg')`

creates another folder `document` inside the bucket `document`

so the actual path would be `document/document/Test15.jpg`